# UIDocumentInteractionController disable copy

Tags: ios, copy, uidocumentinteraction

How to disable 'copy' option in the files that are displayed in the UIDocumentInteractionController? Looks like there was some delegate till iOS6 , which was then deprecated. So, what is the way to achieve this in iOS7 and later?